# find() vs map() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have the following array, and I want to change the value of a property inside one of the objects:

```
var array = [{id: 1, exampleBoolean: false}, {id: 2, exampleBoolean: false}];
```

I've always used `map` for something like this, but I saw someone use `find` instead and am curious if that is a legitimate way to do it? The following functions both technically work (at least in Chrome), but I want to know if they're both technically "correct". Reading docs, my interpretation is that you should use `map`, but it isn't 100% clear to me whether or not I am right.

With find:

```
changeValueWithFind(id: number) {
  array.find(item => item.id === id).exampleBoolean = true;
}
```

With map:

```
changeValueWithMap(id: number) {
    array = array.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          exampleBoolean: true,
        }
      }
      return item;
    });
  }
```

Comment: `.map()` goes through all entries then creates a new array using the function supplied. `.find()` locates a specific entry by a predicate and returns it. They are both "legitimate" in the sense that these are both things that the methods are supposed to do. Which one is more appropriate depends on what result you're after.

Comment: So if your goal is to merely change one property in one object, `find` probably makes more sense?

Comment: Yes, most likely. Unless you want to avoid mutating the array or the objects. But most of the time it's going to be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually using `map()` in this case would be an anti-pattern. `map()` is intended to be used to generate a new array processing individually each of the elements in the original one, and not modifying them. In order to go through the elements modifying them I'd recommend `forEach` instead.

The solution with `find()` in this case is cleaner, but also take into account that `find()` could return `undefined` in case the element is not found.

That way, your example could be modified to:

```
changeValueWithFind(id: number) {
  const myElem = array.find(item => item.id === id);
  if (myElem) {
    myElem.exampleBoolean = true
  }
}
```

Comment: "*map() is intended to be used to generate a new array processing individually each of the elements in the original one, and not modifying them*" the `.map()` callback in the question doesn't modify anything. It *does* create a new array in a pure manner.

Comment: I agree, thanks for the clarification. My comment about it was actually for your requirement "I want to change the value of a property inside one of the objects". But agree that your example code with `map()` does not modify the original one.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion in that case you need use the find().
Doesn’t see any reason to use map() here.

When to use map?
.map() when you want to transform elements in an array.
When to use find?
.find() When you want to select a single element from an array.

More essential info:

https://medium.com/@JeffLombardJr/understanding-foreach-map-filter-and-find-in-javascript-f91da93b9f2c